# why am I getting 'function takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were gien error', when I passed the right number of arguments?

Tags: python, class

I am getting the following **error**:

```
@pytest.fixture
    def mts_parser():
        """MTS parser fixture
        """
        mts = exchanges.get("MTS.CASH", db_write=False, filename='bondreference_20171023.txt')
>       mts.get_subparser()(mts, b'')

tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py:27: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <exchanges.impl.mts.parser.MTSParser object at 0x7ff46564a640>, obj = Dataset MTS.CASH
data = b'', context = None

    def __call__(self, obj, data, context=None):
        self.parser = obj
        self.logger = obj.logger
>       self.parse_er_data(data,context)
E       TypeError: parse_er_data() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

exchanges/protocols/mixins.py:113: TypeError
```

I have the `class Subparser`, which look like this:

```
def __call__(self, obj, data, context=None):
    self.parser = obj
    self.logger = obj.logger
    self.parse_er_data(data,context)
```

Inside `mts`, I have the following functions:

```
def get_subparser(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'subparser') or self.subparser.filename != self.filename:
        self.subparser = self.subparser_cls(self.filename, self.data_group)
    return self.subparser

def parse_er_data(self, bytes_data, context):
    self.get_subparser()(self, bytes_data, context)
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the error above. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The `self` argument is automatically added by python. You do not need to set it in the `get_subparser()` line in `parse_er_data()`. Try for example this to see how it works:

```py
>>> class SomeClass:
...     def some_method(self, argument):
...         print(argument)
...
>>> inst = SomeClass()
>>> func = inst.some_method
>>> func('foo')
foo
```

Note, that the call to `func()` has only one argument, while `some_method()` has two in its definition.